# PhoneGap Build - Application Folder?

Tags: cordova

I really need some help with this. I am building an app that needs to be able to download new content from a server - and add,replace that content within the already installed app.

Currently, I am just simply trying to grab the application folder, but even that is proving difficult. What I do now - listen for deviceReady and then request the file system like so:

window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFSSuccess, null);

This works fine. In onFSSuccess I then try to get a directory entry:

fileSystem.root.getDirectory("data/data/com.gmrmarketing.humana.recipes/images", {create:false}, gotDir, gotError);

So, here's the issue. I've tried Android/data and data/data as shown. Both seem the same. When I set create:true I get error: 12 in gotError - which as far as I can tell means the folder exists. When I use create: false I get error: 1, which I think is a not found error.

Getting these two errors makes no sense... I thought getDirectory would return the directory if it exists, and create if not - not error on both.

Can anyone please give me a hand here? I've got an upcoming deadline and this is really stopping me from getting any further.

Comment: check your path properly in the device you are trying to test, also irrespective of device, you will get the directory path using entry.fullPath, so you can append your project specific folders to build the exact path as required.

Comment: Thanks. I've managed to get it mostly working now. One thing I still cannot get to work is actually replacing a file in my app. I have a recipes.xml file packaged with the app... I need to replace that file from a file on the server. I can download it, and place it in the package folder but the app doesn't use that file. Any ideas?